# Subquery Has too Many Columns: Finding the item bought most frequently by the customers who spent the most

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: Products (prod_id, prod_name, prod_price), Customers (cust_id, address, email, name), and Sales (sale_id, cust_id, prod_id).

I wrote a query to find the top 100 customers (in terms of total money spent on any products):

```
SELECT TOP 100 C.name AS customer_name,
SUM(P.prod_price) AS total_spent
FROM customers C
LEFT JOIN Sales S ON C.cust_id=S.cust_id
LEFT JOIN Products P ON S.prod_id=P.prod_id
GROUP BY C.cust_id
ORDER BY total_spent DESC;
```

This works (I think). Now I want to write a query to find the item that each of those customers bought the most times. So essentially I want to use the first query for a list of names, and then find the item that each of the people on that list bought the most. It doesn't matter how ties are resolved.

I first tried writing it with a nested subquery:

```
SELECT P.prod_name as best_seller,
C.name AS customer_name
FROM products P
JOIN Sales S ON P.prod_id=S.prod_id
JOIN Customers C on S.cust_id = C.cust_id
WHERE C.name IN
    (SELECT TOP 100 C.name AS customer_name,
    SUM(P.prod_price) AS total_spent
    FROM customers C
    JOIN Sales S ON C.cust_id=S.cust_id
    JOIN Products P ON S.prod_id=P.prod_id
    GROUP BY C.name
    ORDER BY total_spent)
GROUP BY C.name, P.prod_name;
```

This gives me the error "Invalid operation: subquery has too many columns;".

When I try not selecting the total_spent in the inner query, like this:

```
SELECT P.prod_name as best_seller,
C.name AS customer_name
FROM products P
JOIN Sales S ON P.prod_id=S.prod_id
JOIN Customers C on S.cust_id = C.cust_id
WHERE C.name IN
    (SELECT TOP 100 C.name AS customer_name
    FROM customers C
    JOIN Sales S ON C.cust_id=S.cust_id
    JOIN Products P ON S.prod_id=P.prod_id
    GROUP BY C.name
    ORDER BY SUM(P.prod_price))
GROUP BY C.name, P.prod_name;
```

I get results but they're wrong (it's a different selection of customers, and they all show the same product for the one they bought most often, which shouldn't be the case).

I want to use this query to test the query time of my db under different circumstances, so I don't necessary want to make it faster or better. I just can't figure out how to do it as a nested query.

Comment: This is tagged Postgres but uses `SELECT TOP`, which is SQL Server (and probably Sybase) syntax. Which DBMS are you really using?

Comment: Instead of a `WHERE … IN …` (with names), you could use a `JOIN … USING (cust_id)`, which doesn't limit the column selection of your subquery

Comment: Can you check what database you are using? It seems you may be confusing PostgreSQL with SQL Server or even Sybase.

Comment: I'm running the query on Amazon Redshift, which the Amazon user guides say is based on Postgres. But I have just been using the little bit of SQL-type syntax I know because I wasn't sure how different they were. I guess the query editor on Redshift must also accept SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

If it's PostgreSQL (your query syntax points to SQL Server or Sybase) the query you can use is:

```
select
  c.name as customer_name,
  sum(p.prod_price) as total_spent
from customers c
left join sales s ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id
left join products p ON s.prod_id = p.prod_id
group by c.cust_id
order by sum(p.prod_price) desc
limit 100
```